# What do multiple slashes in METAR mean?

Tags: weather, metar, taf

The current METAR for Stanstead in the UK says:

> EGSS 031520Z AUTO 29011KT 9999 FEW021/// //////TCU 07/02 Q1022

I do not know how to interpret the /// and //////. From what I remember multiple slashes means that data is missing, however the data in this metar seems complete.

- What does FEW021/// mean?
- TCU means Towering Cumulous, which makes sense, but what do the leading ////// mean in this context?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Complete, unless you want to know the height of base of those TCU's!

The bulk of the information you're after can be found in [AIS-GEN 3.5](http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/pamslight/pdf/4e415453/EG/C/EN/AIP/GEN/EG_GEN_3_5_en) Section 10.17 - AUTO METAR coding

In describing the coding used by automated systems, it gives this example

> NNNhhh/// Cloud detected, but it is unknown whether it is a convective cloud type (ie TCU or CB)

And this one

> //////TCU Towering Cumulus detected, but no information on its height or cloud cover is available

Which more-or-less covers your two questions, I hope.

Answer (score 5):

It means that the report is from an automated weather station and information from sensors are not available for visibility etc.

From [AIP Australia](https://www.airservicesaustralia.com/aip/current/aip/general.pdf):

> 12.20.1 A report from a fully automated AWS that does not include information from sensors for visibility, weather or cloud will report ////, // or ////// respectively in lieu of these parameters.

For this METAR, it can be seen that there are a few clouds at 2100 (with further data missing) and there is towering cumulus, with further data (cloud amount and height missing). For example, decoding this METAR at [flightutilities.com](http://www.flightutilities.com/MRonline.aspx) gives:

> Location: EGSS
>
> LONDON - STANSTED - ENGLAND
>
> Report emitted the day: 03, time 15:20 UTC
>
> Wednesday 3 February 2016 20:50 local time.
>
> Report is fully automated, with no human intervention or oversight.
>
> Wind: True direction = 290 degrees, speed: 11 knots (20 km/h) (6 m/s).
>
> Minimum horizontal visibility: 10 km or more.
>
> Clouds: A few (1-2 oktas), at 2100 feet above aerodrome level (640 meters), but it is **unknown whether it is a convective cloud type**.
>
> Clouds: **cloud type not reported, the cloud base is under the station level or not reported**, towering cumulus.
>
> Temperature: 7 degrees Celsius (45 Fahrenheit). Dewpoint: 2 degrees Celsius (36 Fahrenheit). Relative humidity 70.47 %. Wind Chill: 4 degrees Celsius (38 Fahrenheit).
>
> QNH (Sea-level pressure): 1022 hPa (30.18 inches).

(I've removed some data and added emphasis).

Comment: Ooh I like that Flight Utilities link - I'm terrible at deciphering METAR, that should help, thanks. (Edit: Oh, it's too clever and actually goes to look up the METAR rather than purely decoding it, damn - useful, but I was hoping to use it a little more literally. Still handy though)

Comment: It looks like that reference for Australia doesn't match how the slashes are used in the U.K. (both instances of the slashes in the question are cloud-related and the triple slash isn't even listed as an option in that AIP quote, for example.)